# What do the end users of my program need in order to use it?

Tags: c#, sql

I created a c# program which relies solely on .NET and SQL Server. What do the end-users need to install in order to use my program? I know they have to install .NET Framework but I'm unsure if the program will work without the appropriate SQL files. or am I wrong?

I'm sorry if this question is rather misguided but this is my first program.

Comment: Is the SQL Server a remote instance?  If it is not, they'll need to install the necessary SQL Server components as well.

Comment: The lowest-cost solution is to have them install SQL Server Express (assuming you don't use any features only available in paid versions). There are a number of databases that don't require separate installation, but using them would almost certainly require some rework to your code. SQLite is popular. Google `lightweight database C#` for more options

Comment: I'm only using the database to save data locally. Do i need to reconfigure anything else? I'm concerned with the connection string being different, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is using SQL Server you will need to install SQL Server AND the database your application is looking for.
.NET Framework does not include SQL Server but SQL Server will install the .NET Framework. ([SQL Server 2016 installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#Anchor_0))
SQL Server 2016 Express had a LocalDB version that may suit your needs.  [LocalDB is a lightweight version of Express that has all its programmability features yet runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration installation.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)
Good luck with your first program. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand that I have to replace my connectionstrings to match with the SQL Express version?